# Excel | Get all column/row names in which a specific text is as a list

Tags: list, excel-formula, multipleselection

It is difficult for me to describe the problem in the title, so excuse any misleading description.

The easiest way to describe what I need is with an example. I have a table like:

```
   A   B   C
1  x
2  x   x
3      x   x
```

Now what I want is the formula in a cell for every single column and row with each of the column or row name for every x that is placed. In the example like:

```
        A   B   C
       1,2 2,3  3
1 A     x
2 A, B  x   x
3 B, C      x   x
```

The column and row names are not equivalent to the excel designation. It works with an easy WHEN statement for single cells (=WHEN(C3="x";C1)), but not for a bunch of them (=WHEN(C3:E3="x";C1:E1)). How should/can such a formula look like?

Comment: Hmm, you would want to be able to concatenate an array formula. This used to not be possible in Excel without a UDF but google sheets supported it. Don;t know if this is still the case though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer to my problem. Excel provides the normal `CONCATENATE` function. What is needed is something like a `CONCATENATEIF` (in German = `verkettenwenn`) function. By adding a module in VBA based on a thread from [ransi from 2011 on the ms-office-forum.net](http://www.ms-office-forum.net/forum/showthread.php?t=273352) the function `verkettenwenn` can be used. The code for the German module looks like:

```
Option Explicit


Public Function verkettenwenn(Bereich_Kriterium, Kriterium, Bereich_Verketten)
    Dim mydic As Object
    Dim L As Long
    Set mydic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For L = 1 To Bereich_Kriterium.Count
        If Bereich_Kriterium(L) = Kriterium Then
            mydic(L) = Bereich_Verketten(L)
        End If
    Next
    verkettenwenn = Join(mydic.items, ", ")
End Function
```

With that module in place one of the formula for the mentioned example looks like: `=verkettenwenn(C3:E3;"x";$C$1:$K$1)`

The English code for a `CONCATENATEIF` function should probably be:

```
Option Explicit


Public Function CONCATENATEIF(Criteria_Area, Criterion, Concate_Area)
    Dim mydic As Object
    Dim L As Long
    Set mydic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For L = 1 To Criteria_Area.Count
        If Criteria_Area(L) = Criterion Then
            mydic(L) = Concate_Area(L)
        End If
    Next
    CONCATENATEIF = Join(mydic.items, ", ")
End Function
```

Comment: Glad to see you found the answer